# TypeError error while using isin function to filter rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I met a TypeError error while using isin function to filter rows of my dataset in Pandas

```
df[~df['id'].isin('134399', '187013')]
```

The results:

```
df[~df['id'].isin('134399', '187013')]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-91-ba70cce02a1c>", line 1, in <module>
    df[~df['id'].isin('134399', '187013')]

TypeError: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Does someone know how to deal with this issue and can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a single argument to `isin` (the extra one that's being counted in the 2 or 3 is `self`). You're passing two. That is, your argument should be a list containing the values you want to test against.

```
df[~df['id'].isin(['134399', '187013'])]
```

Comment: My mistake, thanks. BTW, apostrophe on id is not very necessary, right?